# the debugging finish without completing the debug

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-development-serv

I debug my code as usual , and put set of break points but i note that the debugging finish without completing the cycle !!

and this is happened in a dummy manner . How to fix this problem ?

Comment: May be some exception is occurring which is causing the application to crash, you may step into the method and see if you can determine the cause of the exception

Comment: Then why i can't see this exception during my debug or after returning to the page in the browser !

Comment: Or maybe the main thread is exiting without debugger hits the breakpoint.

Comment: What 's the steps can i do to complete my debug please ? especially there's no specific line the debugger finish in it every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have problems with the break points I go and delete the `.suo` file that is a hidden file with the same name as the project on the same directory with the project and keeps among other information's, the debug break points.

Always make a backup first.

Comment: where can i find this file please??

Comment: @just_name Is in the same directory with your project file (and have the same name, just ending on .suo) - is just hidden.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this

1.) Run-> type inetmgr

2.) From the Application Pools, select the name of the application pool that you are working on.

3.) Right click and select Advance Settings

4.) Under Process Model, increase the value of "Ping Maximum Response Time" to say for example 9000

5.) Also try increasing the value of the "Ping Period"

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it skipping the breakpoints? If so, I had this problem on Visual Studio 2008, and had to apply this patch:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1796

Comment: no it's not skipping the break points it enters in it then during the loop it 's out without any exception !!

Comment: Is it executing in the order it should, or does it jump back to an earlier point in the code sometimes? If it skips around, that patch mgiht still fix it, if not, it's not the same problem I had.